# Integrating the function Im(z) on a variety of contours.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analyticity, complex-integration

- I've been asked to evaluate $\int_C Im(z) dz$ for a variety of contours, which I've had no issue in doing.
- For the sake of clarity, these contours included the upper and lower
  halves of the circle with radius 2, centre zero,
- and the line
  segments from $-2$ to $-2 - i$ to $2 - i$ to $2$.
- After parametrizing
  and integrating, I acquired values of $-2 \pi i$ for the individual
  halves, and $-4$ for the line integrals.

My question comes in what we can conclude about the $Im(z)$ function. I'm assuming it's meant to be to do with either the analyticity or path dependence/independence of the function, but I'm really not sure.

Any guidance would be fantastic!!

Comment: My guess is that the purpose of the exercise is to demonstrate that $\operatorname{Im}{z}$ is not analytic, and therefore its integral between the same two points is path dependent.

Comment: While I'm aware that the function isn't analytic, I'm unsure how my working actually shows path dependence.

Comment: Is it the fact that the line integrals and the circles both start and end at the same points, but that the values I attain are dependent on the path I've taken?? (IE: going along the segments gives me a different value to going along a semi-circle).

Comment: That's exactly what path-dependence of the integral means, so yes.

Comment: Have you seen Cauchy's theorem: the integral of an analytic function about a closed loop is zero.  The obvious corollary is that the integral of an analytic function between two points is path independent.  The converse is that the integral of a non analytic function between two points may be path dependent.

Comment: I have indeed seen it, I just hadn't matched that up with this problem. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider Cauchy's theorem: the integral of an analytic function about a closed loop is zero. The obvious corollary is that the integral of an analytic function between two points is path independent. The converse is that the integral of a non analytic function between two points may be path dependent.